# Which Linux kernels include a particular bug fix?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

How do I know which Linux kernels have merged a particular bug fix?

For example, as mentioned in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/422254/143394):

Kernel Bug [198357 - iwlwifi: failed to remove key (1, ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) from hardware (-22)](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=198357) shows:

- `CLOSED CODE_FIX`
- Kernel Version: 4.15.0-rc6-00048-ge1915c8195b3
- Regression: Yes

How do I find out:

- Which kernels prior to 4.15 will include the bug fix
- At what point that the fix has actually been merged in

Comment: I don't this has been actually merged into mainline yet (see [recent iwlwifi commits](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/search?o=desc&q=iwlwifi+mvm&s=committer-date&type=Commits&utf8=%E2%9C%93), or [the wireless patches list](https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/linux-wireless/list/?submitter=150371&state=*)).

Comment: I agree, this patch hasn’t been merged yet (so it won’t hit mainline before 4.16, after which it might be backported to the stable branches).